# Why my program use so much memory?

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks

For just a 25mb file the memory usage is constant at 792mb! I thought it had to do with my usage
from list, but moving certain parts of the code for vector (the arrays where fft is applied, for example) didn't change how much memory being used at all!

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings,BangPatterns #-}
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Char8 as Ap
import Data.Attoparsec
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
--import Control.DeepSeq (force)
import System.IO 
import System.Environment
import Data.List (zipWith4,unzip4,zip4,foldl')
import Data.Bits
import Data.Complex
import Data.String (fromString)
import Data.ByteString.Internal
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as Bl 
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as Vu
import qualified Statistics.Transform  as St



{-
I run a test on a collection of data from a file
[(1,t),(2,t),(3,t),(4,t),(5,t)]
   -     -     - 
   |     -     -     -
   |     |     -     -     -
   |     |     |
 [y++t,  n,  y++t]
To do that, I use splitN to create a list of list
[[(1,t),(2,t),(3,t)],[(2,t),(3,t),(4,t)],[(3,t),(4,t),(5,t)]]
Map a serie of functions to determine a value for each inner collection,
and return when an event happened.



-}

data FourD b a = FourD  a a a b

instance Functor (FourD c) where  
    fmap f (FourD x y z d) = FourD  (f x) (f y) (f z) d  

mgrav_per_bit = [ 18, 36, 71, 143, 286, 571, 1142 ]
--Converting raw data to mg
aToG :: Int -> Double    
aToG a = fromIntegral . sign $  uresult 
    where   
        twocomp = if a>128
                  then 256-a
                  else a
        uresult = sum  $ zipWith (*)   mgrav_per_bit (map (fromEnum . testBit  twocomp) [0..7])
        sign = if a > 128 
               then negate 
               else id


--Data is (int,int,int,time)
--Converted to (St.CD^3,Bytestring) in place of maping afterwards.                  
parseAcc :: Parser (FourD B.ByteString St.CD)
parseAcc = do   Ap.char '('
                x <-  fmap ((:+0) . aToG) Ap.decimal  
                Ap.char ','
                y <-  fmap ((:+0) . aToG) Ap.decimal
                Ap.char ','
                z <-  fmap ((:+0) . aToG) Ap.decimal
                Ap.char ','
                time <- takeTill (== 41)
                Ap.char ')'
                return $! FourD x y z time
--applies parseAcc to many lines, fails at the end of file (Need to add a newline)
parseFile = many $ parseAcc <* (Ap.endOfInput <|> Ap.endOfLine)


readExpr input = case parse parseFile  input of
     Done b val -> val
     Partial p -> undefined
     Fail a b c -> undefined 

unType  (FourD  x y d z) = (x ,y ,d ,z)          


-- Breaks a list of FourD into smaller lists, apply f and g to those lists, then filter the result based if an even happened or not
amap  :: (Num c, Ord c) =>     ([a] -> [c]) -> ([d] -> [ByteString]) -> [FourD d a] -> [Bl.ByteString]
amap f g = (uncurry4 (zipWith4 (filterAcc))). map4 f g . unzip4 . map (unType)
    where map4 f g (a,b,c,d) = (f a,f b,f c,g d)
          uncurry4 f (a,b,c,d) = f a b c d 

-- before  i had map filterAcc,outside amap. Tried to fuse everything to eliminate intermediaries

-- An event is detected if x > 50
filterAcc  x y z t = if x > 50
                                then  (Bl.pack . B.unpack) $ "yes: " `B.append`  t  
                                else  ""
-- split [St.CD] in [(Vector St.CD)], apply fft to each, and compress to a single value. 
-- Core of the application
fftAcross :: [St.CD] -> [Int]
fftAcross = map (floor . noiseEnergy .  St.fft) . splitN 32 

-- how the value is determined (sum of all magnitudes but the first one)
noiseEnergy  :: (RealFloat a, Vu.Unbox a) => Vu.Vector (Complex a) -> a
noiseEnergy  x = (Vu.foldl' (\b a-> b+(magnitude a)) 0 (Vu.drop 1 x))/32

-- how the values are split in (Vector St.CD), if lenght > 32, takes 32, otherwhise I'm done
splitN :: Vu.Unbox a => Int -> [a] -> [Vu.Vector a]
splitN n x =  helper x 
    where
    helper x   = if     atLeast n x 
                 then   (Vu.take n (Vu.fromList x)) : (helper  (drop 1 x) )
                 else  []
-- Replacing the test by atLeast in place of a counter (that compared to length x,calculated once) reduced the behaviour that memory usage was constant.     

-- this is replicated so the behaviour of splitN happens on the time part of FourD, Can't use the same since there is no Vector Bytestring instance                
splitN2 n x =  helper x 
    where
    helper x   = if   atLeast n x 
                 then  (head   x) : (helper  (drop 1 x))
                 else  []

atLeast :: Int -> [a] -> Bool
atLeast 0 _      = True
atLeast _ []     = False
atLeast n (_:ys) = atLeast (n-1) ys



main = do    

    filename <- liftM head getArgs
    filehandle <- openFile "results.txt" WriteMode
    contents <- liftM readExpr $ B.readFile filename
    Bl.hPutStr (filehandle) .  Bl.unlines .  splitAndApplyAndFilter  $ contents where
        splitAndApplyAndFilter  = amap fftAcross (splitN2 32)
```

Edit: after some refactoring, fusing some maps, reducing length, I managed to get this working at 400~ with a 25mb input file. Still, on a 100mb, it takes 1.5gb.

The program is intended to determine if a certain event happened ina  point of time, for that it requries a collection of values (im using 32 atm), runs a fft in it, sum those values and see if passes a threshold. If yes, print the time to a file.

http://db.tt/fT8kXPKz for a 25mb testfile

Comment: And it usually helps people if you give an example file (or format, or file generator)

Comment: In order to make it easier for people to help you, you should improve the layout of your code. The layout is not too bad but not good either. Start by adding a type signature to every top level function. Next, if a function needs more than one line, add a line break after the equality sign. Use one space between each pair of arguments of a function and no space after a left and no space before a right parenthesis. Finally, use expressive function names, even if most Haskell programmers are satisfied with function names like f ;)

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: I updated OP with more information, sorry for not being clearer before. 

I did profiling, but maybe I'm not interpreting correctly?
After discovering -hr I saw that splitN was responsible for a lot of data, and taking out lenght reduced the memory use (even though this didn't make sense for me, why length forced the whole data structure to stay in memory?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution due a topic in reddit about the same problem!
[Parsing with Haskell and Attoparsec](http://newartisans.com/2012/08/parsing-with-haskell-and-attoparsec/)

The great majority of my problem was caused by the fact attoparsec is strict and haskell data are rather large (so a 100mb text file can be actually much more in run time)

The other half was that profiling doubles the memory use, and I didn't account for that.

After changing the parser to be lazy, my program uses 120mb in place of  800mb (when input size is 116mb), so sucess!

In case this interest someone, here is the relevant piece of code change:

```
readExpr input = case parse (parseAcc<*(Ap.endOfLine<*Ap.endOfInput<|>Ap.endOfLine)) input of
     Done b val -> val : readExpr b
     Partial  e -> []
     Fail _ _ c -> error c
```

The full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings,BangPatterns #-}
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Char8 as Ap
import Data.Attoparsec
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
--import Control.DeepSeq (force)
import System.IO 
import System.Environment
import Data.List (zipWith4,unzip4,zip4,foldl')
import Data.Bits
import Data.Complex
import Data.String (fromString)
import Data.ByteString.Internal
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as Bl 
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as Vu
import qualified Statistics.Transform  as St


{-
I run a test on a collection of data from a file
[(1,t),(2,t),(3,t),(4,t),(5,t)]
   -     -     - 
   |     -     -     -
   |     |     -     -     -
   |     |     |
 [y++t,  n,  y++t]
To do that, I use splitN to create a list of list
[[(1,t),(2,t),(3,t)],[(2,t),(3,t),(4,t)],[(3,t),(4,t),(5,t)]]
Map a serie of functions to determine a value for each inner collection,
and return when an event happened.



-}

data FourD b a = FourD  a a a b

instance Functor (FourD c) where  
    fmap f (FourD x y z d) = FourD  (f x) (f y) (f z) d  

mgrav_per_bit = [ 18, 36, 71, 143, 286, 571, 1142 ]
--Converting raw data to mg
aToG :: Int -> Double    
aToG a = fromIntegral . sign $  uresult 
    where   
        twocomp 
            | a>128     = 256-a
            | otherwise =     a
        uresult = sum  $ zipWith (*)   mgrav_per_bit (map (fromEnum . testBit  twocomp) [0..7])
        sign 
            | a > 128   = negate
            | otherwise =     id


--Data is (int,int,int,time)
--Converted to (St.CD^3,Bytestring) in place of maping afterwards.                  
parseAcc :: Parser (FourD B.ByteString St.CD)
parseAcc = do   Ap.char '('
                x <-  fmap ((:+0) . aToG) Ap.decimal  -- Parse, transform to mg, convert to complex
                Ap.char ','
                y <-  fmap ((:+0) . aToG) Ap.decimal
                Ap.char ','
                z <-  fmap ((:+0) . aToG) Ap.decimal
                Ap.char ','
                time <- takeTill (== 41)
                Ap.char ')'
                return $! FourD x y z time
--applies parseAcc to many lines, fails at the end of file (Need to add a newline)
parseFile = many $ parseAcc <* (Ap.endOfInput <|> Ap.endOfLine)


readExpr input = case parse (parseAcc<*(Ap.endOfLine<*Ap.endOfInput<|>Ap.endOfLine)) input of
     Done b val -> val : readExpr b
     Partial  e -> []
     Fail _ _ c -> error c 

unType  (FourD  x y d z) = (x ,y ,d ,z)          


-- Breaks a list of FourD into smaller lists, apply f and g to those lists, then filter the result based if an even happened or not
amap  :: (Num c, Ord c) =>     ([a] -> [c]) -> ([d] -> [ByteString]) -> [FourD d a] -> [ByteString]
amap f g = (uncurry4 (zipWith4 (filterAcc))). map4 f g . unzip4 . map (unType)
    where map4 f g (a,b,c,d) = (f a,f b,f c,g d)
          uncurry4 f (a,b,c,d) = f a b c d 

-- before  i had map filterAcc,outside amap. Tried to fuse everything to eliminate intermediaries

-- An event is detected if x > 50
filterAcc  x y z t 
              | x > 50    = t
              | otherwise = ""

-- split [St.CD] in [(Vector St.CD)], apply fft to each, and compress to a single value. 
-- Core of the application
fftAcross :: [St.CD] -> [Int]
fftAcross = map (floor . noiseEnergy .  St.fft) . splitN 32 


-- how the value is determined (sum of all magnitudes but the first one)
noiseEnergy  :: (RealFloat a, Vu.Unbox a) => Vu.Vector (Complex a) -> a
noiseEnergy  x = (Vu.foldl' (\b a-> b+(magnitude a)) 0 (Vu.drop 1 x))/32


-- how the values are split in (Vector St.CD), if lenght > 32, takes 32, otherwhise I'm done
splitN :: Vu.Unbox a => Int -> [a] -> [Vu.Vector a]
splitN n x =  helper x 
    where
    helper x   
            | atLeast n x = (Vu.take n (Vu.fromList x)) : (helper  (drop 1 x) )
            | otherwise   = []

-- Replacing the test by atLeast in place of a counter (that compared to length x,calculated once) reduced the behaviour that memory usage was constant.     

-- this is replicated so the behaviour of splitN happens on the time part of FourD, Can't use the same since there is no Vector Bytestring instance                
splitN2 n x =  helper x 
    where
    helper x   
            | atLeast n x = (head   x) : (helper  (drop 1 x))
            | otherwise   = []

atLeast :: Int -> [a] -> Bool
atLeast 0 _      = True
atLeast _ []     = False
atLeast n (_:ys) = atLeast (n-1) ys

intervalFinder :: [ByteString]->[B.ByteString]
intervalFinder x = helper x ""
    where
    helper (x:xs) "" 
        | x /= ""   = ("Start Time: " `B.append` x `B.append` "\n"):(helper xs x)
        | otherwise = helper xs ""
    helper (x:xs) y
        | x == ""   = ( "End   Time: "`B.append`  y `B.append` "\n\n" ):(helper xs "")
        | otherwise = helper xs x
    helper _ _      = []

main = do
    filename <- liftM head getArgs
    filehandle <- openFile "results.txt" WriteMode
    contents <- liftM readExpr $ B.readFile filename
    Bl.hPutStr (filehandle) .  Bl.fromChunks . intervalFinder . splitAndApplyAndFilter  $ contents 
    hClose filehandle
    where
         splitAndApplyAndFilter  = amap fftAcross (splitN2 32)  





    --contents <- liftM ((map ( readExpr )) . B.lines) $ B.readFile filename


   {-     *Main> let g = liftM ((amap fftAcross (splitN2 32)) . readExpr) $ B.readFile "te
stpattern2.txt"
-}

   -- B.hPutStrLn (filehandle)  . B.unlines . map (B.pack . show ) .  amap (map (floor .quare) .  (filter (/=[])) . map ( (drop 1) . (map (/32)) . fft ) . splitN 32) . map ( fmap(fromIntegral . aToG)) . map readExpr $ contents
```